# WordPress plugin include css from subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a question about including an css file (WordPress) for my metabox styling in the backend. I have read the ebook "Building WordPress Theme From Scratch" from Rockable. They had the following snippet of code that link to the css (in same folder):

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php include(dsslider-manager.css'); ?>
</style>
```

That's works fine, but I want to organize my css in a subfolder like: assets/css/dsslider-manager.css

But there will no linking to the file. When I look with firebug there is an error, but when I past the url that's given, it will link to the right place...

The error is:

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /customers/0/d/a/xxx.xx/httpd.www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ds-flexslider/includes/cpt-manager.php on line 66

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is due you are trying to include a remote file, which it is not recommend anyway.
So download `dsslider-manager.css` to a local folder inside your plugin and include it like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('my_css_dsslider', PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/css/dsslider-manager.css');
```

But that is not all that you need to successfully include assets files. Check following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898529/how-to-load-jquery-first-in-wordpress/13899024#13899024) for a complete review of how to do it (css and js files) in the right way.

Once you have learned you will can do the same in all your plugins.

Comment: Oke thanks for your answer. But I tought Rockables ebook learned me the right way, because the following snippet of code works fine when the css is in the same directory as the php file where I include the css file...Like so:

`<style type="text/css">
<?php include(dsslider-manager.css'); ?>
</style>`

I thought you can simply add 'assets/css/' before 'dsslider-manager.css'. But that's not the right way..?

Comment: Use `include` to include css/js files are not the right way in WP. WP has specials commands to do it for you `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`. Those command takes in account several things like include just one time each file so you avoid multiple version running at the same time. That is specially a delicate issue with js files. Take some time and study the link I showed you. All those tips have their reason explained in the [WP codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation). I included related links at bottom of that answer. Please feedback after your test. :)

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine. So include is not the right way to other scripts and css to link to a wordpress plugin. Rock Able maintains or include to use, but this works only when the css file in the same directory as the php file? Why does it do anyway?

Thank you for your quick solution, I do have another question about certain Metabox upload media, and whether it is possible to duplicate feature that uploads to place, to upload slider images ... I will put a new message for account ..

Comment: Solution:

`function load_admin_script() {
 wp_enqueue_script('ui-js', DSSLIDER_PATH . 'assets/js/ui-slider.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_enqueue_style('dsslider-manager', DSSLIDER_PATH . 'assets/css/dsslider-manager.css');
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_script' );
`

Comment: @casper Terrific! Very happy for you. Please check my answer as correct so we both gain reputation... 8)

Comment: I am very happy and it's Christmas! I had post an new treated perhaps you can help me out with that problem :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043002/wordpress-metabox-field-image-upload

Happy Christmas!

Comment: THX Casper! Merry XMAS too!